# Saving different sets of values of variables with a changing structure

Tags: memory, data-structures, plc, st

I have several sets of values (factory setting, user setting...) for a structure of variables and these values are saved in a binary file. So when I want to apply certain setting I just load the specific file containing desired values and these values are applied to the variables accordingly to the structure. This works fine when the structure of variables doesn't change.

I can't figure out how to do it when I add a variable but need to retain the values of the rest (when a structure in a program changes, I need to change the files so that they would contain the new values accordingly to the new structure and at the same time keep the old ones).

I'm using a PLC system that is written in ST language. But I'm looking for some overall approach for solving this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
I think your question is too broad for this platform.

Comment: @JimHawkins How about for example using XML? But I still can't think of any reasonably simple way to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an easy task to provide a solution that is generic and works with different plc platforms. There are many different ways to accomplish this depending on the system/interface you actually want to use e.g. PLC Source Code / OPC / ADS / MODBUS / special functions, addins from the vendor and there are some more possibilities e.g. language features on the PLC. I wrote three solutions to this with C#/ST(with OOP Extensions) and ADS/OPC communication, one with source code parsing first in C#, the other with automatic generation from PLC side and another with an automatic registration system of the parameters with an EntityFramework compatible Database as ParameterStore. If you don't want to invest too much time in this you should try out the parameter management systems that are provided by your plc vendor and  live by those restrictions.